# Comparing distances between two sets of proportional vectors (one set length 20 and one length 4)

Tags: vectors

I'm looking for  a way to compare distances between two sets of proportional vectors: one set of length $20$ and one of length $4$. All vectors sum to $1$. Ideally, I would like to be able to ask "is the distance between the individual vectors of length $20$ and their mean greater on average than the distance between the individual vectors of length $4$ and their mean?"

I'm fairly certain that this is not a duplicate, although there are many related things, none seem to exactly answer my question.
Apologies if this is a naive/stupid/obvious question!

Comment: Hint: $d(\vec{u}, \vec{v}) = \| \vec{u} - \vec{v} \| = \sqrt{(u_1 - v_1)^2 + (u_2 - v_2)^2 ... (u_n - v_n)^2}$

Comment: sure, but aren't the distances incomparable because of the differences in dimensionality? Or is that not the case?